# C++ как добавить DLL в компилируемый файл

Tags: c++

я использую внешние библиотеки при написании программы и при запуске она пишет, что библиотеки не найдены. Кончено можно просто добавить эту длл в папку с программой и она запуститься, но это не тот результат, который мне нужен. Как в Visual Studio подключить длл к проекту, чтобы он компилировался и программа не требовала ее?

Comment: В общем случае это не получится. Нужна статически компонуемая библиотека, а она не всегда доступна. Но если доступна — используйте ее.

Comment: @Harry я ее и подключаю к проекту, но он требует dll всеравно

Comment: у некоторых библиотек могут быть свои зависимости. Тут лучше написать, что именно у Вас за библиотека и как Вы ее подключаете

Comment: @KoVadim VMProtect sdk, lib файл и include к нему, все должно работать, но пишет, зависимость к dll

Comment: Файл может называться lib, но при этом быть для динамической линковки